# Is there a general meaning of "free"?

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, soft-question, definition

I am trying to get a clear view of "free nilpotent group". It seems I am not familiar with the use of word free. The word free is also used in other unrelated context, for example "free probability". The link of those basic definition is below:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_probability

https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Free_nilpotent_group

Is there a common way to interpret the word free? I would like to know what exactly the word free mean in case of Nilponent group?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_object

Comment: It often means something along the lines of "Without any relations or restrictions". At least in algebra.

Comment: Thank you, never got that link before. I can accept as an answer if anybody writes an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From comments:

The Wikipedia article [Free object](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_object) gives a category-theoretic description of the usual meaning of "free" in abstract algebra and related fields.